# Getting the result of a checkbox in php

Tags: php, html

How I can get the result of a checkbox (marked or not) by php code?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="new" style="float:right" />
```

Comment: If the checkbox was checked, it will be set, otherwise it won't. Therefore you need `if( isset($_POST['new']) )`. You can fill in the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['new'])){ }
```

Will tell you if it was checked. If you want to be able to check the value as well you need to give the input a value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="new" value="someval" style="float:right" />
<?php
if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new'] == 'someval'){ }
```